# What kind of loop is required here

Tags: php, loops, multidimensional-array

I have an array of wheel data (dimension, application(radius of the wholes) and the price).
I would like to loop over it to fill a table. Unfortunately I can't figure out the logic what kind of loop is required here. I have been trying for days now :(

```
$wheel = array (
'DIMENSIONS_EACH' => array (
    '7,0 x 16',
    '7,5 x 17',
    '8,0 x 17',
    '8,0 x 18',
    '8,5 x 17'
),
'APPS_EACH'=> array (
    '5 x 120',
    '5 x 120',
    '5 x 120',
    '5 x 120',
    '5 x 120',
    '5 x 120'
),
'PRICE_EACH'=> array (
    '96',
    '117',
    '118',
    '155',
    '156',
    '204'
    )
);
```

The Result should be like this for the first row and so son:

```
Dimension | Application | Price
7,0 x 16     5 x 120     96,- €
7,5 x 17     5 x 120    117,- €
....
```

It would not make sense to post my wrong solutions, because I have dozens and none works. Please give me a hint what kind of loop is required here. Thanks a lot.

Comment: What kind of loop you want to use. you can try `foreach` with `key=> value`.

Comment: How do you want to handle the fact that you only have 5 elements in the first, but 6 in the other two?

Comment: I'm going to correct my data :-)

Comment: @user2424222: Use a `for` loop: http://codepad.viper-7.com/TmQYPG

Comment: Thank you for so much input and sharing your knowledge - wooow

Comment: @user2424222 I you can you should consider recreating your array. I do not know your data source, but putting things together like

`array(
 array(
  'dimension' => ...,
  'application' => ...,
  'price' => ...,
 ),
 array(
  'dimension' => ...,
  ...
 ),
)`

would be a lot easier to handle.
Also you have not so much of a problem if you run into a problem like the one @PatrickQ pointed out.

Comment: Yes I can recreate and structure it in a different way. I forgot to mention that I want to create a function, that renders a product page. Therefore I would like to leave the function untouched and just give it the arguments of the wheeldata. I'm going to open a repository on Bitbucket.

Comment: git clone git@bitbucket.org:rgmarketing/rg-oxxo.git Original Page[link]http://www.oxxo-wheels.de Rebuild with new mega menu and render function for page[link]http://sandbox.reifengundlach.de/oxxo/ Please see bestla.php and renderWheel.inc.php for details - Thank you everyone : Feel free to fork

Answer (score 1):

You're going to need two nested `foreach` loops.

```
foreach ($wheel as $type => $items) {
    foreach ($items as $item) {
        // Perform your insert
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If every entry is in the correct order and given that each array is of the same length. We get the count first and loop through via the index.

```
$count = count($wheel['DIMENSIONS_EACH']));
```

After that you can do a for loop to access each index in the three arrays.

```
$count = count($wheel['DIMENSIONS_EACH']);
$table = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
    $table[] = array(
        $wheel['DIMENSIONS_EACH'][$i],
        $wheel['APPS_EACH'][$i],
        $wheel['PRICE_EACH'][$i]
    );
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($table);
```

http://ideone.com/QfgyaI

Comment: It works in the demo, but in my function it seems I'm missing parts of the array :( - see the BitBucket Repo to fork if you like

Comment: @user2424222 Wheres the fork? And are all the arrays of the same length and all indexes?

Comment: git@bitbucket.org:rgmarketing/rg-oxxo.git It's still uploading See file bestla.php to understand what I'm trying to achieve. TY in advance / everyone

Comment: Download the whole package here as a rar file [link](http://sandbox.reifengundlach.de/oxxo.rar) Download works Bitbucket push failed / driving home now

Answer (score 0):

I'd solve it like this (untested code -> no warranty):

```
$content = <<< heredoc
<html>
    <head><title>UNTESTED</title></head>
    <body>
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Dimension</th>
            <th>Application</th>
            <th>Price</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
       <tbody>

heredoc;

$count = count($wheel);

for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
  $dimension = $wheel["DIMENSIONS_EACH"][$i];
  $apps = $wheel["APPS_EACH"][$i];
  $price = $wheel["PRICE_EACH"][$i];

  $content .= <<< heredoc
  <tr>
    <td>$dimension</td>
    <td>$apps</td>
    <td>$price</td>
  </tr>
heredoc;
}

$content.= <<< heredoc

    </tbody>
  </table>
</html>
heredoc;

echo $content;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
foreach($wheel['DIMENSIONS_EACH'] as $key=>$value ){

  echo $value. "-".$wheel['APPS_EACH'][$key]."-".$wheel['PRICE_EACH'][$key]."<br>";

}
```

See demo [here](https://eval.in/115583)

Comment: Thank you for giving another perspective